# DateTime to UTC

Tags: c++, boost, c++-chrono

What is the proper way to convert date time values to UTC in milliseconds?

I've been looking into std::chrono and boost without really finding a pragmatic way to accomplish this, any ideas?

i.e.

```
auto local_time_to_utc_milliseconds(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond) -> std::uint64_t
{
    return ???;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean milliseconds since "the Epoch" (or some wellknown timepoint):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76da8fda1ff2bfad)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    static const boost::posix_time::ptime epoch { { 1970, 1, 1 }, {} };

    auto now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

    std::cout << "Time in milliseconds since 1970: " << (now-epoch).total_milliseconds() << "\n";
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Time in milliseconds since 1970: 1432566946471
```

**Update** to match your signature:

```
auto local_time_to_utc_milliseconds(boost::posix_time::ptime& dt) -> std::uint64_t
{
    static const boost::posix_time::ptime epoch { { 1970, 1, 1 }, {} };
    return (dt - epoch).total_milliseconds();
}

auto local_time_to_utc_milliseconds(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond) -> std::uint64_t
{
    return local_time_to_utc_milliseconds(boost::posix_time::ptime { { year, month, day }, { hour, minute, second, millisecond } });
}
```

Comment: ptime::total_milliseconds doesn't exist?

Comment: @ronag No. Does it have to? The docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#time_duration_constr

Comment: Hah. It happens. I was a bit suirprised at the comment because I had a live demo of it. This explains :) Cheers!